# How to read, update and pass variables between functions that are placed in different .js files?

Tags: node.js, function, variables, discord.js, global

So, I'm working on a discord bot that has a few functions. I'm using node.js and discord.js.
I broke down the code into a few files because it was getting too long, so now I need something to pass global variables between functions and update them each time.

The first approach I tried was through parameters, but then the variables weren't going to change for the other functions.

1.

```
async function prepare(message, parameters)
{
  // Code here
}
```

For the second approach I tried using a JSON object. To read and update the values I used `readFile` and `writeFile`.
The problem was that when writing the JSON object, some datas were lost, because for some reasons the values were simplified, and that created errors afterward. In particular, the value ruined was from a `ReactionCollector` object.

2.

```
// Reads external JSON object.
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('config.json');
let obj = JSON.parse(rawdata);

// do something with obj.

// Writes JSON object.
let data = JSON.stringify(obj);
fs.writeFileSync('config.json', data);
```

My last attempt was using a different type of writeFile function, that preserved the datas, but it created problems when reading the JSON object multiple times.

3.

```
// Reads external JSON object. 
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
var data = await readFile('../config.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
let obj = JSON.parse(data);

// Do something.

// Updates JSON object.
fs.writeFile('../config.json', packageJson, { encoding: 'utf8' }, err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Wrote json.");
});
```

Anyone that could make this code work?

Comment: Did you stringify the data every time you wanted to write it?

Comment: If you want to pass something where the caller can see the change too, then pass an object with properties and modify the properties of the object.  Objects are passed by pointer so when you modify a property in the object, everyone who has a reference to that object will see the same change.  Plain values like numbers or booleans, etc.. are not passed as a pointer so the caller won't see your change.

Comment: I did, my bad I forgot to add it to the code. The problem I get using that code is the following:
`Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the best and simpler way is to use getter/setter functions for each variable.

This is an example:

```
var binary_tree = [];

function setBinary_tree(bt)
{
    binary_tree = bt;
}

function getBinary_tree()
{
    return binary_tree;
}

module.exports.setBinary_tree = setBinary_tree;
```

And then here it's how the variables are passed into the external file:

```
const { getBinary_tree, setBinary_tree } = require('./path/variables.js');

var binary_tree = getBinary_tree();

// Do something with the variable.

// At the end, updates the variables.
setBinary_tree(binary_tree);
```